# Prevent table column border from touching bottom or top of table

Tags: html, html-table, border

I'm creating a table in html, and the line border between two columns extends fully up and down. How can I change it so that it doesn't touch the top of the table or the bottom of it?

```
              <title>Home Styles</title>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
                  content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
               <style type="text/css">
                 p {font-size:small; margin-left: .2in }
               }
             </style>
              </head>
            <h1>Central Valley Construction</h1>
              <h2>Home Styles</h2>

                <table border="1" frame="hsides" width="1170px">
             <tr>
              <td valign="top" 
             style="border-right: 1px black solid; padding- top:70px"align="center">
              <a href="Chalet.html">Chalet</a><br />
              <a href="ContemporaryRanch.html">Contemporary Ranch</a><br />
              <a href="Cottage.html">Country Cottage</a>
              </td>

            <td align="center" style="padding-top:40px">



              <img src="chalet.jpg" alt="Image of a chalet" height="113" width="200" />
              <p><strong>Style</strong>: chalet</p>
              <p><strong>Square feet</strong>: 1305<br/>
             <strong>Bedrooms</strong>: 3<br />
             <strong>Baths</strong>: 2</p>


            </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </body>
```

Comment: First, consider not doing layout with tables, second, have an element inside the `tr/td` that has margin on the top and bottom

Comment: IT has to be done with tables, unfortunately but i will try the margin

Comment: I'll change my fiddle below to tables.

Comment: That would be awesome thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LwKGG/1/

Answer (score 1):

Have an element inside the `tr/td` that has margin on the top and bottom. I used `div`s below, but its the same concept.

### Update version, with tables

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LwKGG/1/

```css
.wrap{
    width:500px;
    background:#ccc;
    height:300px;
}

.border{
    margin:20px 5px;
    padding:10px;
    border-right:solid 3px #000;
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}

.right{
    height:150px;
    background:#369;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="wrap">
        <td>
            <div class="border">
            Lorem ipsum.... blah blah blah.
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="right">
            Lorem ipsum.... blah blah blah.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Original version

```css
div {
  float: left;
}

.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 800px;
}

.border {
  margin: 20px 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: solid 3px #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

.right {
  height: 150px;
  background: #369;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="border">
    Lorem ipsum.... blah blah blah.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Lorem ipsum.... blah blah blah.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! I updated your answer to include the linked JsFiddle as a runnable code snippet. However, I did not want to delete the original version which was in your answer, and differs from the JsFiddle. Please consider whether you want to keep it. Thanks!